# C Find the largest number in array

Tags: c

I'm new to C and what I'm trying to do is ask the user to input 10 numbers in which it will then find the largest one. However, sometimes it just prints the last number inputted as the largest and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
void find_largest()
    {
        int numbers[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            printf("Enter a number: ");
            scanf("%d", &numbers[i]);
        }
        int largest = numbers[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            if (numbers[i] > numbers[0])
            {
                largest = numbers[i];
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n", largest);
    }
```

Comment: `if (numbers[i] > numbers[0])` should be `if (numbers[i] > largest)`

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code? Or at least put a couple of `printf()` here and there to know what it was doing

Comment: @dratenik Yeah your right, dumb mistake by me thank you for the help!

Comment: @JackLilhammers Got no clue how to do that new to c and new to coding

Comment: @sinisterfang you can use onlinegdb.com, their debug mode is so clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you assigned the value of largest element is array's first element. But after this operation you should check the largest element with all of the array's number. If the one of the element in the array is larger then the largest variable, you should assign this value to the largest variable until checking the last element.
So you should change `numbers[i]>largest`